# Accessing Global Dictionary via two separate threads return different results

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary

I'm having trouble when trying to access a global dictionary which holds objects as values.

Within the code, one thread (`TestAccess`) will listen to web connections and create objects and update its variables, assign a key to it and insert in to the global dictionary (`client_list`) accordingly. While the other thread (`data_cleaner`) will go through the list of keys in this global dictionary and check for certain values in each object and will delete objects if it meets certain criteria.

The objects I'm creating (`clientObject`) attaches another object (`deviceObject`) when it gets created - just so you know.

When I run both threads, the thread that should check objects (`data_cleaner`) will not see the dictionary being updated. It always returns `{}`. If I run the functions without any treads and both returns the correct dictionary values as expected.

I have tried the `global` keyword but had no luck. Also added a `Lock()` just to make sure we don't have any simultaneous resource access issues.

Can someone please shed some light on this? Following is the structure of my code.

```
import web
import json
import threading
import time

urls = (
'/testaccess', "TestAccess"
)

client_list = {}
lock = threading.Lock()

class clientObject(object):
    # each created object here will attach another object from from deviceObject  below

class deviceObject(object):
    # Object items

class TestAccess:
    def __init__(self):
       pass

    def GET(self):
        return "abcd"

    def POST(self):
        raw_data = web.data()
        json_dic = json.loads(raw_data)
        process_data(json_dic)


 def process_data (json_dic)
    global lock
    global client_list

    lock.acquire()

    # Perform some processing on the JSON data.

    if XXXXXXXXXXXX:
        # Create the new object and and update values.

        client_list[ID] = clientObject()
        client_list[ID].XX[ID].pred_vals(jsonInfo)
    else:
        # Update the object

    print client_list # This prints all key:value pairs nicely as expected.

    lock.release()

def data_cleaner()
    global lock
    global client_list
    while True:
        lock.acquire()

        print client_list # this prints out just  "{}"

        # Do other things
        lock.release()
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = web.application(urls, globals())

    def start_web_server():
        app.run()

    T2 = threading.Thread(target=data_cleaner)
    T1 = threading.Thread(target=start_web_server)

    T1.daemon = False

    T1.start()
    T2.start()
```

Comment: check http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Comment: What is `web` here? Are you running a Flask or other such framework for the web server?

Comment: Ah, judging by the code you are running [`web.py`](http://webpy.org/). That project uses a [CherryPy WSGI server](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/3.2.6/refman/wsgiserver/index.html), so it uses threads already. Investigating if they use forking to support code reloading.

Comment: Are you using the `web.reloader` middleware at all?

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry, I'm not quite sure if I'm using web.reloader without my knowlege. But I don't specifically call for "web.reloader" anywhere within my code.. if that's what you are asking for. The only thing I'm doing with the web.py is listening on the TCP port, and whenever  it sees a connection it just dumps data for further processing and it just keeps listening. I only call it once inside the __main__ initially. Hopefully this will give you a clue :)

Comment: @shamax: you need to explicitly use the reloader, I think, so that possibility is out.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks Martijn. I will give this a try and let you know. Also just so you know, the web server itself if working fine and it is updating the Global Dictionary with the correct data (=objects related to the data). It's just that I can't access the same Dictionary from the other Thread. When I try to access this from the other Thread.. it returns an empty dict {}. But If I access the Dict from within the Thread that updates the Dict, I see its getting populated.

Comment: I didn't say that using the reloader would fix this. Some web frameworks (like Flask) use a separate child process to facilitate reloading, and those don't share globals after forking. If you are running this in a WSGI server that uses multiple processes to handle load however, you'll see the same problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks Martijn. I will get back to you once I test this out.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Since you mentioned the autoreloader, I played with that parameter and when I did the "autoreloader = False", it worked !. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction and being patient :)

Answer (score 1):

With MartijnPieters help I was able to resolve this issue by adding the "**autoreloader = False**" as a parameter when creating the web object as shown below.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=False)

    def start_web_server():
        app.run()

    T2 = threading.Thread(target=data_cleaner)
    T1 = threading.Thread(target=start_web_server)

    T1.daemon = False

    T1.start()
    T2.start()
```